# Best way to zoom/expand element: CSS or jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I want to know what the best way is to expand the size/zoom of an element when you hover over it: **CSS or jQuery?**

I made this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FCxfR/8/) with CSS transition, but it does not do what I want, widht and height does not size smooth and proportionally:

```
<div></div>

div{

    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background: #aa00aa;
    -moz-transition: height 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: height 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: height 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transition: height 0.3s ease-in-out;

    -moz-transition: width 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: width 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: width 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transition: width 0.3s ease-in-out;

}

div:hover{
    background: #aa00aa;
    height: 400px;
    width: 400px;

}
```

Comment: CSS is a way more consistent and clean way of doing this. You should only consider jquery if you need backward compatibility with older browsers (which is only the case if the transition is an important part of your application logic, not only a design issue).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This transition makes your box larger

```
transition: width 1s ease-in-out, height 1s ease-in-out;
```

But to achieve a real zoom effect you would need to move the box to the left and top at the same time. Something like this http://jsfiddle.net/slash197/FCxfR/14/

Comment: thank you very much, appreciate. How would you achieve this with jQuery for older browsers?

Comment: this same thing can be done in jquery with `.animate` http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Answer (score 1):

Transitions work just like any other CSS rule.  If you had:

```
color: red;
color: green;
```

...the color would be green.  In this case, the transition is only being applied to `width`.  You can specify both:

```
transition: height 0.3s ease-in-out, width 0.3s ease-in-out;
```

or as

```
transition-property: height, width;
transition-duration: .3s;
transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
```

or even

```
transition-property: height, width;
transition: .3s ease-in-out;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FCxfR/13/

Comment: thank you very much, appreciate. How would you achieve this with jQuery for older browsers?